# Combining partial matches in rows of a single table in Access database

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a table that looks like the one below:

```
Product   1       2      3       4       5        6      7       8       9
005778  110023  112623  117273  4371    4377    50563           
070370  110023  112623  1930    40007   4216    4310    4318    4428    56257
010702  110023  112623  2392    40007                   
012702  110023  112623  2392    40007                   
017965  110023  112623  2392    40007                   
017966  110023  112623  2392    40007                   
034350  110023  112623  2622    40007   56257               
024940  110023  112623  2622    40007   56257               
071300  110023  112623  40007   4215    4216    4218    4321    56257   
071330  110023  112623  40007   4215    4216    4218    4321    56257
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Product                         1          2      3      4       5        6      7       8       9
005778                        110023    112623  117273  4371    4377    50563           
070370                        110023    112623  1930    40007   4216    4310    4318    4428    56257
010702/012702/017965/017966   110023    112623  2392    40007                   
034350/024940                 110023    112623  2622    40007   56257               
071300/071330                 110023    112623  40007   4215    4216    4218    4321    56257
```

I have attempted to use Allen Browne's ConcatRelated() without success. I am attempting to combine this data to use in an Access 2010 report. VBA or SQL solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to add a Calculated field to the table to concatenate fields [1] through [9] together as a string, i.e.,

```
Field Name: ValuesString
Expression: "|" & [1] & "|" & [2] & "|" & [3] & "|" & [4] & "|" & [5] & "|" & [6] & "|" & [7] & "|" & [8] & "|" & [9] & "|"
Result Type: Text
```

Then you can use `ConcatRelated()` like so

```sql
SELECT 
    Max(ConcatRelated("Product","YourTable","ValuesString=""" & [ValuesString] & """","","/")) AS ProductList, 
    Max(YourTable.[1]) AS MaxOf1, 
    Max(YourTable.[2]) AS MaxOf2, 
    Max(YourTable.[3]) AS MaxOf3, 
    Max(YourTable.[4]) AS MaxOf4, 
    Max(YourTable.[5]) AS MaxOf5, 
    Max(YourTable.[6]) AS MaxOf6, 
    Max(YourTable.[7]) AS MaxOf7, 
    Max(YourTable.[8]) AS MaxOf8, 
    Max(YourTable.[9]) AS MaxOf9
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY YourTable.ValuesString;
```

returning

```
ProductList                  MaxOf1  MaxOf2  MaxOf3  MaxOf4  MaxOf5  MaxOf6  MaxOf7  MaxOf8  MaxOf9
---------------------------  ------  ------  ------  ------  ------  ------  ------  ------  ------
005778                       110023  112623  117273    4371    4377   50563                        
070370                       110023  112623    1930   40007    4216    4310    4318    4428   56257
010702/012702/017965/017966  110023  112623    2392   40007                                        
034350/024940                110023  112623    2622   40007   56257                                
071300/071330                110023  112623   40007    4215    4216    4218    4321   56257
```

Comment: Worked great. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

in SQL2005 or later, you can try something like:

```
select products, t.*
from ( select distinct [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9] from tbl ) t
    cross apply (select products = stuff(
        (select '/' + product from tbl z 
         where z.[1] = t.[1] AND z.[2] = t.[2] ... AND z.[9] = t.[9] 
         for xml path(''))   --concat list
       , 1,1,'') ) z         --remove first '/'
```

You will need to do `isnull(z.[1],'') = isnull(t.[1],'')` etc. if they can be null.

Comment: The question is tagged MS Access and wasn't edited for 15 minutes before you posted this answer.